# Cross-Browser text-align:center

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to align center an image inside a `<li>`  element. This is a gallery, so I don't have much freedom to play with css rules.

I was trying adding the rule

```
text-align:center;
```

to the `<li>` element, but no succes. So I tryied with the rule

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

and it works only in chrome.
For Firefox I found

```
text-align: -moz-center;
```

but I don't find anything for other browsers?
Someone know what rules I have to use?

Comment: Try to add display: block; to your <li>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using flexbox? it might be worth taking a look at it (e.g. using the justify-content rule)

Answer (score 0):

[Try using Flex.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  flex-direction: column;
```